# extract a dictionary from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary which has the following structure in a python program
`{'John':{'age': '12', 'height':'152', 'weight':'45}}`, this is the result returned from a function.

My question is how may I extract the sub-dictionary please? so that I can have the data in this form only `{'age': '12', 'height':'152', 'weight':'45}`.

*I can think of a solution of using for loop to go through the dictionary, since there is only one item in this dictionary, I can then store it into a new variable, but I could like to learn an alternative please

Many thanks

Comment: Did you try `d["John"]`? Or if there is only one value and you don't know the key  just pull it from .values. `next(iter(d.values()))`  or `d[next(iter(d))]`

Comment: Read the dictionary part of any Python tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

To get a value from a dictionary, use dict[key]:

```
>>> d = {'John':{'age': '12', 'height':'152', 'weight':'45'}}
>>> d['John']
{'age': '12', 'height': '152', 'weight': '45'}
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> d = {'John':{'age': '12', 'height':'152', 'weight':'45'}, 'Kim':{'age': '13', 'height': '113', 'weight': '30'}}
>>> for key in d:
...     print(key, d[key])
... 
John {'height': '152', 'weight': '45', 'age': '12'}
Kim {'height': '113', 'weight': '30', 'age': '13'}
```

Just access the subdictionary with `d[key]`. If you have multiple keys, something like the above loop will allow you to go through all of them.

Comment: i think this is the solution, thanks!

Comment: Please vote up and mark this answer as accepted if you think it's the solution :)